# UserNotificationsUI.framework error at ios 9 in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

**I need  support both iOS 9 & 10 for push notification** . How can i do it ? I am looking for some idea .  I used  **UserNotificationsUI.framework**. But it crash at **iOS 9** .

Answer (score 1):

both a new and old framework

If you diff SDK 'iOS 10.0'(Xcode 8) and SDK 'iOS 9.0' with this command below, you will find six UIKit classes related to notifications are deprecated in SDK 'iOS 10.0'(Xcode 8) .

UIKit9Dir="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework"
UIKit10Dir="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework"

OptIgnore=--ignore-matching-lines='//.*Copyright'
DIFFBIN=/usr/bin/diff
$DIFFBIN -U 1 -r -x '*.tbd' -x '*.modulemap' $OptIgnore $UIKit9Dir $UIKit10Dir|egrep -C 1 "NS_CLASS_DEPRECATED_IOS.*"|grep interface

Have both the method implemented while working

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"10.0")) {
```

## if XCODE_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO_8

```
    /// schedule localNotification, the delegate must be set before the application returns from applicationDidFinishLaunching:.
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
```

## endif

```
} else {
    UILocalNotification *localNotifacation = [self getLocalNotificationFromLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
    if (localNotifacation) {
        NSString *title = localNotifacation.alertBody;
        [self addLabel:title];
    }
}
```

Then implement whatever remote Notification methods you need.

Comment: I said  UserNotificationsUI.framewor error .

Comment: #import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h> framework error at ios 9 . Can you explain why ?

Comment: @ZahirulIslam `<UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>` framework is available from iOS 10

Comment: Then, how i support both ios 9 & 10 for push notification ? any idea?

Comment: @ZahirulIslam http://ashishkakkad.com/2016/09/push-notifications-in-ios-10-objective-c/

Comment: If you diff SDK 'iOS 10.0'(Xcode 8) and SDK 'iOS 9.0' with this command below, you will find six UIKit classes related to notifications are deprecated in SDK 'iOS 10.0'(Xcode 8) .

Comment: I need to implement Delegate for iOS 10 , but that is not available in iOS9 . So, how can i differ this two ? please explain